# Why refreshing page when I using data-ng-if Angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I need to show below div when my screen is bigger than 1700 pixels, but I have a non standard problem: when `isMonitorIsBig === false`, my DOM is not refreshing, but I have all the page refreshing  and after that this block is showing correctly.

```
<div class="some classes" data-ng-if="!isMonitorIsBig">... .. . ... </div>
```

The need of refreshing the whole single page application after I changed the window width it's not very comfortable, how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you share your controller code?

Comment: Why? I'm using only directive which showing my html. But with refreshing of page...

Comment: It might be because you set the object to another value, angular loses the `$watch` and it does not get picked up in the digest cycle

Comment: For example                 $scope.bigSizing = 1700;
                $scope.isMonitorIsBig = window.innerWidth > $scope.bigSizing

Comment: When are you calling this method?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use CSS for this, with media-queries:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1700px) {
    .lg-hide {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="lg-hide">This div hides on a screen with a width > 1700px</div>
```

Comment: it's not correct. Because all div's will be loaded in the page